# Maven and Gradle Stuck at Unit Tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing, gradle

Everything was running fine till my VM (Ubuntu 17.10, VM Player) crashed while running integration tests (I had a lot of background tasks running). Now Unit Tests are getting stuck on both maven and gradle. However when I clone the same code on another machine, everything is smooth (Same branch). What I've tried so far :-

- Restarted VM
- Restarted Host Machine
- Reinstalled Maven and Gradle
- Deleted .M2 Folder
- Clone the repo somewhere else
- Debugged Tests Cases
  Stack trace on where it gets stuck :-

> ```
> Project Test Debug [Remote Java Application]  
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM [localhost:5005]  
>       Thread [main] (Running) 
>       Thread [SUITE-ConfigReaderTest-seed#[2282DD601D0CC6CD]] (Suspended) 
>           Native.invokeLong(Function, long, int, Object[]) line: not available [native method]    
>           Function.invoke(Object[], Class<?>, boolean, int) line: 421 
>           Function.invoke(Method, Class<?>[], Class<?>, Object[], Map<String,?>) line: 354    
>           Library$Handler.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 244  
>           $Proxy39.syscall(NativeLong, Object[]) line: not available  
>           SystemCallFilter.linux_syscall(long, Object...) line: 257   
>           SystemCallFilter.linuxImpl() line: 280  
>           SystemCallFilter.init(Path) line: 639   
>           JNANatives.tryInstallSystemCallFilter(Path) line: 258   
>           Natives.tryInstallSystemCallFilter(Path) line: 113  
>           Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Path, boolean, boolean, boolean) line: 111  
>           BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>() line: 79 
>           ESTestCase.<clinit>() line: 175 
>           Class<T>.forName0(String, boolean, ClassLoader, Class<?>) line: not available [native method]   
>           Class<T>.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: 348    
>           RandomizedRunner$2.run() line: 592
> ```

Meanwhile, everything is working fine on all other machines.
But on this machine, Maven and Gradle always get stuck on Unit Tests (No test actually gets executed), no matter which project I choose.

Comment: Both maven and gradle fork a process to run unit tests. There's likely one or more `java` processes hanging around. If you kill off the processes I'm guessing you'll get a green build.

Comment: @lance-java But I did restart the VM and Host Machine, shouldn't that be fixed already?

Comment: One way to find out! `ps -ef | grep java`

Comment: Got nothing:
vsharma    2442   2123  0 12:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java